# News template like layout for menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a menu which is generated dynamically. Its structure is similar to a newspaper template. I did some research and came to know that using css flexbox we can achieve something like this. However i am still not able to achieve it.
This is the desired look I want:-
[image]

To replicate the issue:- click on 'Bilar' menu item-> check the menu -> the 4th menu item is expected to come a bit upwards, but its comes downwards.
 Below is the codepen link and my code. Any help is appreciated.

[Click this Codepen link to see the current code](https://codepen.io/Aalind/pen/JvLoqp?editors=1100)

```css
$font-stack:    OpenSans, Helvetica, sans-serif;

$primary: #e50000;
$primary-hover: #ca0000;
$text-color: #555555; 
$white: #ffffff;

$graphic-grey-color: #e1e1e1;
$background-grey-color: #f5f5f5;
$main-dark-color: #202020;
$form-border-color: #dddddd;
$form-active-border-color: #999999;

$navbar-light-color: $main-dark-color;
$link-hover-color: $white;
$link-hover-decoration: none;
$nav-tabs-link-active-bg: $primary;
$navbar-brand-padding-y: 0rem;
$navbar-nav-link-padding-x: 0.9375rem;
$nav-link-padding-y: 0rem;

.header-navigation {
    height: 80px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid $primary;
    .header-brand{
        margin-right: 1.4375rem;
        height: 100%;
    }
}

.header-menu{
    height: 100%;
}

.header-menu-item{
    font-family: $font-stack;
    height: 100%;
    color: $main-dark-color;
    &:hover { 
        background-color: $primary;
    }
    + .-collapse{
        z-index: 1000;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 80px;
        left: 0px;
        // display: none;
        opacity: 0;
        .menu-item-level2 {
            width: 100vw;
            margin: auto;
            .-level2-main-section{
                padding: 0px;
                background-color: $background-grey-color;
                min-height: 280px;
    
                .-level2-main-section-row{
                    max-width: 100%;    
                    text-align: center;
                    margin: 30px 165px 50px 165px;
                    .-level2-menu-column{
                        padding: 0px;
                        text-align: left;
                        // .-level2-menu-container{
                            margin-bottom: 30px;
                            .-heading{
                                margin-bottom: 10px;
                                color: $main-dark-color;
                                font-size: 20px;
                                font-weight: bold;
                                line-height: 1.5;
                            }
                            .-subitems{
                                color: $text-color;
                                font-size: 16px;
                                line-height: 1.88;
                            }
                        // }
                    }
                }
            }
            .-level2-side-section{
                margin: auto;
                padding: 20px;
                background-color: $graphic-grey-color;
                min-height: 280px;
                .-info{
                    margin-bottom: 60px;
                    .-info-text{
                        margin-top: 10px;
                        line-height: 1.5;
                        font-size: 20px;
                        color: $text-color;
                        font-weight: normal;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

.header-menu-item.active{
    background-color: $primary;
    color: $white;
    + .-collapse{
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: opacity 500ms linear;
    }
}

.header-menu-list {
    height: 100%;
}

.navbar{
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 30px !important;
    color: $text-color;
}

.header-brandname{
    margin: 10px 0px;
}

.header-logo{
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px 30px;
    border-left: 1px solid $graphic-grey-color;
}
```

Comment: Important to have the longest column in the middle?

Comment: nope. but the content is dynamic and can change. so in some places it will be bigger in the middle and in some it will not.

Comment: You may find [CSS column](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) helpful, but it is not widely supported. Alternatively, use Javscript to make the columns like what Pinterest does. I myself had a similar case and used JS.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `col-lg-4` use the following responsive `media query`:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
.col-lg-4 {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 33.333333%;
}
}
```

wich means that once your browser width is higher than 992px, these colums takes 33.33% width and it should be 25% (if you want 4 columns)

**EDITED:** Just saw your screenshot. css `flex` wont let you do what you want. If the content is fixed you can just add your 4th menu inside first one container, removing `col-lg-4` class like in this **[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pVLyzb?editors=1100)** (Note I added margin-top inline to make it look better.)

If the content is dinamic you may need to search for any other way to achieve it. masonry came to my mind as first thing I would look into: **[link](https://masonry.desandro.com/v2/)**

Comment: No this doesnt work. I have added a screenshot of the desired output I want. Please have a look

Comment: my structure is dynamic. also i dont want to use any external library. Your codepen link is not working. Can you please send it again ?

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle link instead ? i dont know  for some reason the codepen is continuously reloading.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi column for this layout. I have added on last please [**check**](https://codepen.io/caseydev/pen/MGVyap?editors=1100)

```css
.header-navigation {
  height: 80px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e50000;
}
.header-navigation .header-brand {
  margin-right: 1.4375rem;
  height: 100%;
}

.header-menu {
  height: 100%;
}$font-stack: OpenSans, Helvetica, sans-serif;

$primary: #e50000;
$primary-hover: #ca0000;
$text-color: #555555;
$white: #ffffff;

$graphic-grey-color: #e1e1e1;
$background-grey-color: #f5f5f5;
$main-dark-color: #202020;
$form-border-color: #dddddd;
$form-active-border-color: #999999;

$navbar-light-color: $main-dark-color;
$link-hover-color: $white;
$link-hover-decoration: none;
$nav-tabs-link-active-bg: $primary;
$navbar-brand-padding-y: 0rem;
$navbar-nav-link-padding-x: 0.9375rem;
$nav-link-padding-y: 0rem;

.header-navigation {
  height: 80px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid $primary;
  .header-brand {
    margin-right: 1.4375rem;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.header-menu {
  height: 100%;
}

.header-menu-item {
  font-family: $font-stack;
  height: 100%;
  color: $main-dark-color;
  &:hover {
    background-color: $primary;
  }
  + .-collapse {
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 0px;
    // display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    .menu-item-level2 {
      width: 100vw;
      margin: auto;
      .-level2-main-section {
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: $background-grey-color;
        min-height: 280px;

        .-level2-main-section-row {
          max-width: 100%;
          text-align: center;
          margin: 30px 165px 50px 165px;
          .-level2-menu-column {
            padding: 0px;
            text-align: left;
            // .-level2-menu-container{
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            .-heading {
              margin-bottom: 10px;
              color: $main-dark-color;
              font-size: 20px;
              font-weight: bold;
              line-height: 1.5;
            }
            .-subitems {
              color: $text-color;
              font-size: 16px;
              line-height: 1.88;
            }
            // }
          }
        }
      }
      .-level2-side-section {
        margin: auto;
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: $graphic-grey-color;
        min-height: 280px;
        .-info {
          margin-bottom: 60px;
          .-info-text {
            margin-top: 10px;
            line-height: 1.5;
            font-size: 20px;
            color: $text-color;
            font-weight: normal;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

.header-menu-item.active {
  background-color: $primary;
  color: $white;
  + .-collapse {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 500ms linear;
  }
}

.header-menu-list {
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 30px !important;
  color: $text-color;
}

.header-brandname {
  margin: 10px 0px;
}

.header-logo {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px 30px;
  border-left: 1px solid $graphic-grey-color;
}

.menu-wrap {
  display: block;
}

.row.-level2-main-section-row {
  display: block;
  column-count: 3;
}
.-level2-menu-column {
  display: block;
}


.header-menu-item {
  font-family: OpenSans, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  color: #202020;
}
.header-menu-item:hover {
  background-color: #e50000;
}
.header-menu-item + .-collapse {
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
}
.header-menu-item + .-collapse .menu-item-level2 {
  width: 100vw;
  margin: auto;
}
.header-menu-item + .-collapse .menu-item-level2 .-level2-main-section {
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  min-height: 280px;
}
.header-menu-item + .-collapse .menu-item-level2 .-level2-main-section .-level2-main-section-row {
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 30px 165px 50px 165px;
}
.header-menu-item + .-collapse .menu-item-level2 .-level2-main-section .-level2-main-section-row .-level2-menu-column {
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.header-menu-item + .-collapse .menu-item-level2 .-level2-main-section .-level2-main-section-row .-level2-menu-column .-heading {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #202020;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.header-menu-item + .-collapse .menu-item-level2 .-level2-main-section .-level2-main-section-row .-level2-menu-column .-subitems {
  color: #555555;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.88;
}
.header-menu-item + .-collapse .menu-item-level2 .-level2-side-section {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  min-height: 280px;
}
.header-menu-item + .-collapse .menu-item-level2 .-level2-side-section .-info {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.header-menu-item + .-collapse .menu-item-level2 .-level2-side-section .-info .-info-text {
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #555555;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.header-menu-item.active {
  background-color: #e50000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.header-menu-item.active + .-collapse {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 500ms linear;
}

.header-menu-list {
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 30px !important;
  color: #555555;
}

.header-brandname {
  margin: 10px 0px;
}

.header-logo {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px 30px;
  border-left: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
}

.menu-wrap {
  display: block;
}

.row.-level2-main-section-row {
  display: block;
  column-count: 3;
}

.-level2-menu-column {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
    <nav class="header-navigation navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <a class="header-brand navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center pull-left" href="#">
            <img src="/static/images/fc-logo.svg" alt="brand-logo">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#header-navigation" aria-controls="header-navigation"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="header-menu collapse navbar-collapse" id="header-navigation">
            <ul class="header-menu-list navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="header-menu-item nav-link d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                        <span>Bilar</span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="-collapse">
                        <div class="menu-item-level2 row">
                            <div class="-level2-main-section col-lg-10">
                                <div class="menu-wrap">
                                        <div class="-level2-main-section-row row align-items-start">
                                                <div class="-level2-menu-column -level2-menu-container col-lg-4">
                                                    <div class="-heading">Nya bilar</div>
            
                                                    <div class="-subitems">Personbilar</div>
                                                    <div class="-subitems">Transportbilar</div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="-level2-menu-column -level2-menu-container col-lg-4">
                                                    <div class="-heading">Nya bilar</div>
            
                                                    <div class="-subitems">Personbilar</div>
                                                    <div class="-subitems">Transportbilar</div>
                                                    <div class="-subitems">Personbilar</div>
                                                    <div class="-subitems">Transportbilar</div>
                                                    <div class="-subitems">Personbilar</div>
                                                    <div class="-subitems">Transportbilar</div>
                                                    <div class="-subitems">Personbilar</div>
                                                    <div class="-subitems">Transportbilar</div>
                                                    <div class="-subitems">Personbilar</div>
                                                    <div class="-subitems">Transportbilar</div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="-level2-menu-column -level2-menu-container col-lg-4">
                                                    <div class="-heading">Nya bilar</div>
            
                                                    <div class="-subitems">Personbilar</div>
                                                    <div class="-subitems">Transportbilar</div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="-level2-menu-column -level2-menu-container col-lg-4">
                                                    <div class="-heading">Nya bilar</div>
            
                                                    <div class="-subitems">Personbilar</div>
                                                    <div class="-subitems">Transportbilar</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="-level2-side-section col-lg-2">
                                <div class="-info">
                                    <a class="-info-img" href="#">
                                        <img src="/static/images/car.png" alt="info-image-1">
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="-info-text">
                                        Vilken Yaris ar du?
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="-info">
                                    <a class="-info-img" href="#">
                                        <img src="/static/images/car2.png" alt="info-image-2">
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="-info-text">
                                        Basta familjebilen - 7 sittplatser!
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a class="header-menu-item nav-link d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                        <span>Finansiering</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a class="header-menu-item nav-link d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                        <span>Service</span>
                    </a>

                </li>
                <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a class="header-menu-item nav-link d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                        <span>Om oss</span>
                    </a>

                </li>
                <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a class="header-menu-item nav-link d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                        <span>Min Toyota</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="header-logo pull-right  d-flex align-items-center">
                <img src="/static/images/toyota-logo.jpg" alt="brand-logo">
            </a>
    </nav>
</header>
```

[Link](https://codepen.io/caseydev/pen/MGVyap?editors=1100)

Answer (score 0):

One way is using `CSS column`, but is is not widely supported. You can check its [Browser compatibility](https://caniuse.com/#search=column) here.

If you decide to do so, remember you can not combine it with flex. Hence, no Bootstrap flex classes for this part of your page.

1. Use `column-count: #x` for the number of columns in row.
2. Use `break-inside: avoid;` to avoid break column break.

```css
.-level2-main-section-row {
  border: 1px solid;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
}

.-level2-menu-column {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-wrap">
  <div class="-level2-main-section-row  align-items-start">
    <div class="-level2-menu-column -level2-menu-container ">
      <h1 class="-heading">Nya bilar</h1>

      <div class="-subitems">Personbilar</div>
      <div class="-subitems">Transportbilar</div>
    </div>
    <div class="-level2-menu-column -level2-menu-container ">
      <h1 class="-heading">Nya bilar</h1>

      <div class="-subitems">Personbilar</div>
      <div class="-subitems">Transportbilar</div>
      <div class="-heading">Nya bilar</div>

      <div class="-subitems">Personbilar</div>
      <div class="-subitems">Transportbilar</div>
      <div class="-heading">Nya bilar</div>

      <div class="-subitems">Personbilar</div>
      <div class="-subitems">Transportbilar</div>
      <div class="-heading">Nya bilar</div>

      <div class="-subitems">Personbilar</div>
      <div class="-subitems">Transportbilar</div>
      <div class="-heading">Nya bilar</div>

      <div class="-subitems">Personbilar</div>
      <div class="-subitems">Transportbilar</div>
    </div>
    <div class="-level2-menu-column -level2-menu-container ">
      <h1 class="-heading">Nya bilar</h1>

      <div class="-subitems">Personbilar</div>
      <div class="-subitems">Transportbilar</div>
    </div>
    <div class="-level2-menu-column -level2-menu-container ">
      <h1 class="-heading">Nya bilar</h1>

      <div class="-subitems">Personbilar</div>
      <div class="-subitems">Transportbilar</div>
      <div class="-subitems">Personbilar</div>
      <div class="-subitems">Transportbilar</div>
      <div class="-subitems">Personbilar</div>
      <div class="-subitems">Transportbilar</div>
      <div class="-subitems">Personbilar</div>
      <div class="-subitems">Transportbilar</div>
      <div class="-subitems">Personbilar</div>
      <div class="-subitems">Transportbilar</div>
    </div>
    <div class="-level2-menu-column -level2-menu-container ">
      <h1 class="-heading">Nya bilar</h1>

      <div class="-subitems">Personbilar</div>
      <div class="-subitems">Transportbilar</div>
    </div>
    <div class="-level2-menu-column -level2-menu-container">
      <h1 class="-heading">Nya bilar</h1>
      <div class="-subitems">Personbilar</div>
      <div class="-subitems">Transportbilar</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check this [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aGYprv?editors=1100)
You can set different column per page using `media queries`.

## Update

An another problem with column is that it does not respect the order you lay down the columns. Therefore, if its important to order the columns, you may go for [masonry](https://medium.com/wdstack/varying-column-heights-in-bootstrap-4e8dd5338643) or some other Javascript library.

This  [article](https://medium.com/wdstack/varying-column-heights-in-bootstrap-4e8dd5338643) is a good read on this topic.

Comment: yup i checked the column count thing. but i am not sure about the browser compatibility. This is such a basic issue and a library like bootstrap hasnt handled it....thats really strange !

Comment: @AalindSharma I think it is quite complex. You may check Masonry layout. It is quite lightweight.

Comment: unfortunately, i cant add any external library in this project bro :(